# Detect click on notification in web starter kit

Tags: javascript, service-worker, progressive-web-apps, google-web-starter-kit

I am using [Google Web Starter kit](https://github.com/google/web-starter-kit) and notification can be shown using service worker.

```
navigator.serviceWorker.getRegistration().then(function(reg) {
    var options = {
      body: body
    };
    reg.showNotification(title, options);
});
```

I would like to detect **notificationclick** event using the service worker.

[notification behaviour article](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/engage-and-retain/push-notifications/notification-behaviour) states that:

> To achieve this we need to add a 'notificationclick' event listener to
>   our service worker.

I tried the following:

```
navigator.serviceWorker.addEventListener('notificationclick', function() {
  console.log('notificationclick event called');
});
```

But it doesn't seem to work. Where should the event listener be added?

Comment: What is the error log?

Comment: There is no error in the console when I click on the notification which appears on the screen.

Answer (score 0):

You need to put the `notificationclick` event handler inside the service worker file, and use `self.addEventListener` (or just `addEventListener`):

```
# sw.js

self.addEventListener('notificationclick', function() {
  console.log('notificationclick event called');
});
```

Putting it in the service worker file makes sense because if the page/browser is closed, you'd still want the event handler to execute.